# How can ı do kendo grid filter with boolean nullable or false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, null, grid, boolean

I cannot add an empty or incorrect filter to a boolean field in kendo grid. How do I perform this.

Comment: if you could add some code that would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share more details with related code and specific issue

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then we'll better understand your issue to give you an answer.